# Python/Pandas: No counting records above certain value

Tags: python, pandas, windrose

I am trying to make a windrose from Excel data and I need to skip all values bigger than 10 for velocity. The data range is from 0 to 17 and I only want values from 0 to 10 showing on the windrose. How can I achieve that?

```
import pandas as pd
from windrose import WindroseAxes

df = pd.read_excel(r'sheet')

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(df.Dir, df.Vel, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend(loc="upper right")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter out all velocities more than 10.(This won't change the excel file )

```
import pandas as pd
from windrose import WindroseAxes

# I have not seen this way of reading excel files. I thought you would need an engine 
df = pd.read_excel(r'sheet')

# filter out values greater than 10 for velocity and reset the index
df = df.loc[df['Vel'] <= 10].reset_index(drop=True)

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(df.Dir, df.Vel, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend(loc="upper right")
```